# If blogger thumbnail name is x, display y?

Tags: blogger, blogspot, mediatemple

I'm new to editing blogger themes and hope someone that recognizes *<b: if>* code can help out.

This is what I want to learn and put into my blogspot theme:

If a post has a specific thumbnail, or not found, display another image.

Something like this logic?

```
If thumb=='bad_picture_name' .or. thumb=='another_bad_pic_name'

    Display good_picture

Elseif thumb==missing

    Display transparent_gif-thumb

Else

    Display thumb

Endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this : (*works with new themes*)

```
<b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage == "img-src" or data:post.featuredImage == "img-src"'>
         Display good_picture
    <b:else/>
        Display thumb
    </b:if>
<b:else/>
    Display transparent_gif-thumb
</b:if>
```

With old templates (*version 2*) replace `featuredImage` with `firstImageUrl`